# Running the script in the terminal is working perfectly but after creating .sh file run throws error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
for file in Cadence*
do
mv -i "${file}" "${file/John/Krishna}"
done
```

I able to run the script copy and paste on the terminal it is working perfectly, but after creating the .sh file and execute throws the error like syntax error.

```
./bulkCopyFiles.sh > fedora.txt
./bulkCopyFiles.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/bulkCopyFiles.sh: line 2: `do
```

Comment: Where is the shebang? "throws the error like syntax error" It is custom to include the command and actual error message by copy/paste-ing it into the question.

Comment: [agowlika.HSC-PG00AZYD] ➤ ./bulkCopyFiles.sh > fedora.txt
./bulkCopyFiles.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/bulkCopyFiles.sh: line 2: `do

Comment: for file in Cadence*
do
mv -i "${file}" "${file/John/Krishna}"
done

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 issues.

### 1 Line endings

```
syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
```

It looks like you used Microsoft-style line endings (`\r\n` or CR-LF) instead of Unix-style (`\n` or only LF). Most shell interpreters don't like those.

You can convert the line endings with `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix bulkCopyFiles.sh
```

### 2 Interpreter choice / Shebang

You need to put a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning of your *Bash* script to indicate that it should be interpreted by *Bash*.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in Cadence*
do
  mv -i "${file}" "${file/John/Krishna}"
done
```

Otherwise Linux will default to the `/bin/sh` interpreter which is *not Bash* in Ubuntu but some other Bourne-like interpreter with a smaller language feature set (in Ubuntu it's *Dash*). In this case Dash is unfamiliar with Bash’s pattern replacement [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

### Appendix: Shellcheck

Use [*Shellcheck*](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (also available in the eponymous package `shellcheck`) to verify the syntax of your shell scripts. For yours it suggests:

```
Line 1:
for file in Cadence*
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
```

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!